# Join All dataframes which names starts with df

Tags: python, dataframe, join

I've multiple dataframes (with exacly the same structure, same variables...) and they all starts with "df_".

What I would like to do is to join all these dataframes into one.

I can do it manually, but I have many data frames and their names can change.

```
frames = [df_24_10000, df_48_10000, df_64_20000, df_82_30000]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Is it possible to join all data frames that starts with "df_"?

Comment: Just use `df.append` in a for loop ?

Comment: @BcK for that I would need to have the data frames names in a vector? I don't have them

Comment: @BcK That would cause problems if the number of dataframes is large. `pd.concat` would be more appropriate, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally the sign of a design problem. If you find yourself trying to group a number of objects by their names, it means that should have been elements of the same container (list, dict, set, map or whatever) from the very beginning.

Said differently, if instead of `df_24_10000`, `df_48_10000`, `df_64_20000`, you had `dfs['24_10000']`, `dfs['48_10000']`, `dfs['64_20000']`, the join would simply be:

```
result = pd.concat(dfs.values)
```